# Why is MySQL `gtid_owned` session variable always empty after committing a transaction?

Tags: mysql, gtid

I'm testing some work with MySQL Global Transaction IDs (GTIDs) and I'm having a hard time getting the most-recent session GTID. I've enabled GTIDs (global `gtid_mode` is set to `ON_PERMISSIVE`). According to the documentation [for `gtid_owned`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-gtids.html#sysvar_gtid_owned):

> This read-only variable holds a list whose contents depend on its scope. When used with session scope, the list holds all GTIDs that are owned by this client; ...

So, I expect, after committing a transaction, that this session variable would contain GTIDs; but it is always empty, no matter what I do. However, the global `gtid_executed` changes every time I commit a transaction, so I know that GTIDs are working.

Here's a session that demonstrates this issue:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.gtid_executed;
| a1c32161-89c4-11e8-856e-0242ac12001d:1-4 |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_next;
| AUTOMATIC           |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_owned;
|                      |

mysql> START TRANSACTION;

mysql> SELECT @@global.gtid_executed;
| a1c32161-89c4-11e8-856e-0242ac12001d:1-4 |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_next;
| AUTOMATIC           |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_owned;
|                      |

mysql> INSERT INTO ........

mysql> SELECT @@global.gtid_executed;
| a1c32161-89c4-11e8-856e-0242ac12001d:1-4 |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_next;
| AUTOMATIC           |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_owned;
|                      |

mysql> COMMIT;

mysql> SELECT @@global.gtid_executed;
| a1c32161-89c4-11e8-856e-0242ac12001d:1-5 |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_next;
| AUTOMATIC           |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_owned;
|                      |

mysql> INSERT INTO ........

mysql> SELECT @@global.gtid_executed;
| a1c32161-89c4-11e8-856e-0242ac12001d:1-6 |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_next;
| AUTOMATIC           |

mysql> SELECT @@session.gtid_owned;
|                      |
```

Notice that each time a transaction is committed (explicitly or implicitly/autocommit), the global list of executed GTIDs is incremented, but the session `gtid_owned` is always empty.

What am I doing wrong/missing? Or have I found a bug?

Comment: Have you checked if GTID is enabled on configuration file (my.cnf): gtid-mode=ON ?

Comment: `SELECT @@global.gtid_mode;` -> `ON_PERMISSIVE`

Answer (score 0):

A client only owns a transaction that is still open, so `gtid_owned` is cleared once the transaction commits. It also only shows a value if you have explicitly set one for `gtid_next`; using `gtid_next=automatic` will not populate `gtid_owned`. The use of `gtid_owned` is therefore limited to some internal operations and to cases like replication where the GTID is explicitly set in the binary log.

To get the list of gtids set by the current session, you could enable `session_track_gtids` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_session_track_gtids).

Note however that the 'mysql' command line client does not report the values returned by the session tracker; you'd need a client which lets you call the C API functions `mysql_session_track_get_first()` and `mysql_session_track_get_next()` (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-session-track-get-first.html).

Comment: I should have responded to this a long time ago, but I got sidetracked (I had given up on GTIDs). I've come back to it. Part of this response doesn't sound correct to me. The documentation specifically says of `gtid_owned`: "When used with session scope, the list holds all GTIDs that are owned by this client." It doesn't say that `gtid_next` must be set. If it were cleared once a transaction commits, it wouldn't be a LIST of "all GTIDs that are owned by this client." Even if it WERE cleared after every commit, my demonstration above shows that it's empty even during an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication-gtids-lifecycle.html the GTID is not assigned until commit time. That's why it seems empty during the uncommited transaction - if gtid_owned is populated at all on the master, it's only after you've sent the COMMIT; and for the brief instant between when the server picks the GTID and when it writes to the binlog - and of course you'll have no opportunity to view the variable during that time unless you're using GDB or something.

The list of owned GTIDs therefore really only has relevance to a replication slave.

Comment: Try setting up STATEMENT-format logging on a server with gtid_mode on. INSERT INTO someTable VALUES (@@gtid_owned); - you'll see that value is empty on the master, but populated with a GTID on the slave.

Comment: Then what even is the point of this session variable? It seems completely useless to me.

Comment: Correct, it's of very little use to the end user. It exists to help the developers with testing and debugging - if you're writing the code dealing with a multi-threaded slave and some bug is causing transactions to be skipped or duplicated, then it's mighty helpful to know who owns which GTID.

Answer (score -1):

I test it in MySQL 8.0.12, and <= 8.0.12 should have the same results.

[image: gtid_owned]

**Personal opinions, may have some mistakes!**

`Gtid_owned` and `Gtid_executed` are used when generate a new GTID to avoid a duplicate one. And `Gtid_next` affects the timing to use `Gtid_owned`.

If `Gtid_next` is `AUTOMATIC`, GTID is generated when the transaction is in flush stage in commit phase and saved in `Gtid_owned`; source code path in binlog.cc is `MYSQL_BIN_LOG :: ordered_commit() --> MYSQL_BIN_LOG::process_flush_stage_queue() --> assign_automatic_gtids_to_flush_group`;

And `Gtid_owned` will be removed in commit stage, source code is in binlog.cc too, the path is `MYSQL_BIN_LOG::process_commit_stage_queue -> Gtid_state::update_commit_group -> update_gtids_impl_own_gtid_set`;

So you can't get the `Gtid_owned` in this situation because mysql generate it and clear it at the final phase of transaction;

To get the value of `Gtid_owned`, just set `Gtid_next` to a precise gtid, **so it will be saved in `Gtid_owned` immediately(without source code checks)**, so you can check this variable normally as the pic shows;

Another pic, the `global gtid_owned` save the used gtid and the client's thread_id after #, the previous pic shows the thread_id too.
[image: gtied_owned_global]

Comment: This doesn't seem like reasonable behavior, and also doesn't mesh with the documentation. First, in all normal cases, you should never need to set `gtid_next`. Ever. It's more for testing/troubleshooting. Many SQL commands are unavailable when `gtid_next` is not set to `AUTOMATIC`. Only SUPER can change `gtid_next`. As for the `gtid_owned` documentation, it says "the list holds all GTIDs that are owned by this client." ALL GTIDs. That wouldn't make sense if this only held a value between the flush stage and the commit stage. It couldn't hold ALL GTIDs owned by the client were that the case.

Comment: GTIDs is generated between the flush stage and the commit stage, then saved in `gtid_owned`, so next transaction in same client or other clients can get the "the list of all GTIDs that are owned by this client and other client". Therefore MySQL will not generate a duplicate one. This is how I understanding the `gtid_owned` documentation. So `gtid_owned` actully saves the GTIDs used by the client but only in a short time at the end of transaction, and the global values is saved with the client's thread_id so other client can know the all used GTIDs. Maybe it's used by MySQL not users. @NickWill

Comment: For more, set `gtid_next` to precise one may used by slave, because its GTIDs is not generated by itself, but the GTIDs recorded in relaylog(same contents with Master's binlog), so slave have to set a precise gtid. @NickWilliams